# What does CWT amplitude mean?

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet, frequency-analysis

I've a big issue with continuous wavelet transform. I've created this signal

```
t = 0:1/2000:1-1/2000;
dt = 1/2000;
x1 = sin(50*pi*t).*exp(-50*pi*(t-0.2).^2);
x2 = sin(50*pi*t).*exp(-100*pi*(t-0.5).^2);
x3 = 2*cos(140*pi*t).*exp(-50*pi*(t-0.2).^2);
x4 = 2*sin(140*pi*t).*exp(-80*pi*(t-0.8).^2);
x = x1+x2+x3+x4;
```

And its rappresentation on time is 
[image]

Than I computed its Fourier Transform in the classic way

```
Ts =1/Fs; 
N = length(x);
t = 0:Ts:Ts*N-Ts;
FTx = fft(x,N);
S = (abs(FTx).^2)/N; %amplitude
f_FT = (0:Fs/N:Fs-Fs/N);
S = S(1:N/2);  % i reject half signal
f_FT = f_FT(1:N/2);
```

And its rappresentation is [image]
I computed the continuous wavelet transform using the function cwtft

```
  s0 = 2;
a0 = 2^(1/32);
scales = (s0*a0.^(32:7*32)).*dt;
cwtx = cwtft({x,dt},'Scales',scales,'Wavelet',{'bump',[4 0.9]});
figure;
contour(t,cwtx.frequencies,abs(cwtx.cfs))
xlabel('Seconds'), ylabel('Hz');
grid on;
title('Analytic CWT using Bump Wavelet')
hcol = colorbar;
hcol.Label.String = 'Magnitude';
```

[image]

I don't know what magnitude rappresent, and specially why it differs so much with the values obtained with the classic FFT. Is there a way to convert it?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

There are two dimensions present here: Time and Frequency (Scale). The third dimension, which is magnitude or amplitude, shows the intensity of your frequencies (scales, which in wavelets scales are the inverse of frequencies) in those local times.

---

I guess it is much simpler than what I just explained. You are basically looking at a similar image to these three dimensions from the top in your last image in the question:

[image]

#### Source

[Machine Learning with Signal Processing Techniques](http://ataspinar.com/2018/04/04/machine-learning-with-signal-processing-techniques/)